# Am I missing something, or is this invalid?

Tags: ini

I parsed through a bunch of INI files using PHP. Upon doing so, I came across a few errors in the script. I located the problem lines in the files afterwards.

In short, are either of these lines actually valid?

`{section}` (rather than `[section]`; happened in one set, but none of the other sets in the same location)

`[section]=foo`

I'm mostly curious because I don't know whether they've actually caused any errors, or if they're working as the maintainers expected (without knowing that it's a possible typo).

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: Also, please keep in mind this is running on software that is pretty old. Updated somewhat I believe, but created a while ago. Not sure if that matters or things have changed since. The file with curly braces only has one section like that, the rest are brackets.

Comment: @melpomene As in, will programs properly use it, or will it cause errors and not work as expected. Would it stop halfway, or just ignore it and combine the curly brace section with the one above? Just things like that.

Comment: Depends on the programs and how they're written. You need to show some code if you want us to predict what it will do with any given input.

Comment: @melpomene I don't have access to the program source. It's just configuration files for it. I pulled the same file from around 5000 devices across around 300 locations. One cluster of them at location A were like the one example, and another cluster at location B were like the other example. The rest parsed without errors.